# In CiviEvent, can the answer to one question reveal additional questions?

Tags: civievent, registration

We are setting up conference registration using CiviEvent and are wondering if the answer to one question reveal additional questions. For instance, in our old system, you could select "on-site" or "off-site" accommodations and related questions would then be revealed. So this is really a dependency question—can one question showing be dependent upon the selection the user makes for another question. Please take into consideration that we are CiviEvent newbies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is called "conditional visibility". Standard CiviEvent registration does not have this feature. There are several ways to accomplish this, but unfortunately most aren't really newbie-friendly.

The [Profile Conditionals](https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals) extension adds this feature but it's difficult to configure - you have to configure it by hand in `civicrm.settings.php`.

FormBuilder will be the successor to the current CiviEvent pages when complete. It has conditionals in the CiviCRM 5.69+.  However, it doesn't currently process payments, so is only suitable (for now) on free events.

If you're on Drupal or Backdrop, the Webform module has conditionals, and with Webform-CiviCRM, will do what you need.  This is my recommendation if you use one of those CMSes.

WordPress has the "Caldera Forms" plugin with CiviCRM integration.  I don't know the current status of it - there was a meeting yesterday I didn't attend.  Hopefully if you're on WordPress someone can speak to whether that's feasible.

Comment: I was able to get Profile Conditionals working with some trial and error. It will be nice once CiviEvent is using FormBuilder and can use FB's conditionals. This works for now. Thanks for the suggestion!